# What does getiterator() method do?

Tags: symfony, twig

I don't understand the getIterator() methode

Here an exemple where I saw it lately:
(in the following code **$list_articles** is the result of a query which return a list of articles, with their authors, contents, dates and their categorieS) *(one author, content and date for each article, but many categories for each article)*

```
$lastArticle = current($list_articles->getIterator())
return $this->render('XXX.html.twig',array(
    'articles' => $list_articles,
    'Date' => $lastArticle=>getDate()
));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pl/arrayobject.getiterator.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `current()` and `getIterator()` will return the element pointed internally from a (let's call it that way) cursor of an array

Specifically `getIterator()` returns an iterator that could helps you if you don't want to "create" it yourself

`ArrayObject` class implements `IteratorAggregate` that provide this functionality

Comment: Not sur if I understand it.   **$list_articles->getIterator()** transform **$list_articles** (a collection) into an array **($list_articles[])** and current() point to the last value used of this array... Am I right?